# SoapClient call not executing - timeout

Tags: php, soap-client

With PHP, when trying to call some method with SOAP, I always bust the maximum execution time. However, since calling this method worked in the past, when I remove `'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE` it starts working.

If I fetch the WSDL with a `file_get_contents` I get it completely. However, it just doesn't work when I call the method

```
$client = new SoapClient("https://.../file.asmx?wsdl", array(
    'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1,
    'trace' => true,
    'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE
));

$result = $client->SomeMethod($parameters);
```

At some point I was able to get the error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Error Fetching http headers in myfile.php
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: SoapClient->__doRequest('<?xml version="...', 'https://abc.def...', 'http://someser....', 1, 0)
#1 myfile.php(27): SoapClient->__call('SomeMethod', Array)
#2 myfile.php(27): SoapClient->SomeMethod(Object(Z)) #3 {main} thrown in myfile.php on line 27
```

I would love to get more diagnostics errors but I do not know how?
I pay for this WSDL service and it is unusable... Is it this WSDL server's fault? How can I be sure and what can I say to this service provider? The call to SomeMethod doesn't answer in time? (even though I am able to download the WSDL)

Comment: Which part is timing out, getting the wsdl (which should only happen once - or each time you clear the cache be the wsdl has be updated on the soap server), or the actual soap call?

Comment: @EddieJaoude The part that seems to be timing out is the call to `SomeMethod`. Getting the WSDL seems all fine.

Comment: Have you tried different values for `cache_wsdl`?

Comment: @superspace I have, but I don't think this is really helping... If I cache it and the request succeeds once, then it will work for a while.  I strongly believe the problem is the server answering my SOAP being slow or "broken". I just wanted to make sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you said that when you disable **wsdl_cache** then the service starts working.

I had a lot of frustration moments because of having **wsdl_cache** turned "**on**" on my development environments. The thing is that if you have **wsdl_cache** turned **on** on your development environment, then the **SoapClient** object will download the **wsdl** file just the first time you call the service. Then lets suppose you change the return type or the name of an existing function, some times, the **SoapClient** object will not download the new **wsdl** with the new modifications and then the **generated xml soap request** will **no longer match the web service description** anymore, and the call will fail.

This happen to me using **Zend Framework** and the class **Zend_Soap_Client** and generating the wsdl dynamically based on the annotations of the class that i setup to handle the service requests using **Zend_Soap_Autodiscover**.

In linux, php stores the cached wsdl files in side the **/tmp** folder with a filname prefix "**wsdl**". You can go there and delete all those files, then the next request will grab the new wsdl. Or better enough, just **turn off** the wsdl cache settings in your **php.ini** file or just putting this line on the very beginning of the script where you make the call.

```
ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_enabled',0);
```

**PS**: Turning off **wsdl_cache** is recommended on **development environments** because of all the modifications made to the web service source code. Having **wsdl_cache** off can **dramatically slow down the performance on high traffic production environments**. **So i only recommend  it off on development.**

Comment: That's not exactly true. The service seems to answer sometimes. With cache or no cache.
Now, if I set CACHE_NONE, it usually fails. When I remove the WSDL_CACHE, I believe it caches *something*. It probably caches the WSDL, but must cache something else too. The WSDL is **always** available; the call "SomeMethod" seems to do more chat with the server? With cache ON, it seems to work IF it worked at least once.

In the end, I just wanted to make sure that the problem was not PHP, my server or SOAP, but the WSDL service not responding.

Comment: @jsgoupil, Well then you should troubleshot the problem using another client to be sure that is not php the one causing the problem, and see if the problem is in the server. I would suggest you to use SoapUI for that purpose.

Comment: SoapUI ended up to prove that it was not PHP the problem. Thanks for showing me another client.

Comment: @jsgoupil Can you explain what the problem was?

Comment: @superspace We will never know... I believe the server I was calling was at fault. The company asked us to stop using their services and go for a competitor because they can't figure out what's the problem. Terrible customer support.

Comment: I can't believe that answer from a company. Horrible!